# How to find unique combinations in one hot encoded dataframe?

Tags: pandas, apriori

I have a dataframe called test that looks like this

```
+-------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
|       | Term 1  | Term 2  | Term 3  | Final Exam |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
| 1288  |      0  |      0  |      1  |          1 |
| 1290  |      1  |      1  |      1  |          1 |
| 1294  |      0  |      0  |      1  |          1 |
| 1296  |      1  |      1  |      1  |          1 |
| 1297  |      1  |      1  |      1  |          1 |
| 1304  |      0  |      1  |      1  |          1 |
| 1308  |      0  |      0  |      1  |          1 |
| 1324  |      1  |      1  |      1  |          1 |
| 1325  |      1  |      1  |      1  |          1 |
| 1332  |      1  |      1  |      1  |          1 |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+------------+
```

I would like a summary table of all unique combinations where column = 1 along with the number of times it occurs:

```
+-----------------------------------+-----------+
|            Combination            | Frequency |
+-----------------------------------+-----------+
| Term 3, Final Exam                |         3 |
| Term 2, Term 3, Final Exam        |         1 |
| Term 1, Term2, Term 3, Final Exam |         6 |
+-----------------------------------+-----------+
```

I've tried using mlxtend.apriori, but this gives me all occurrences of columns together:

```
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
results = apriori(test,min_support=0.00001,use_colnames=True)
results['length'] = results['itemsets'].apply(lambda x:len(x))
numberofcases = test.shape[0]
results['Frequency'] = results['support'] * numberofcases
results['Terms'] = results['itemsets'].astype(str).str.replace('frozenset\({','').str.replace('}\)','').str.replace('\'','').str.replace('\"','')
results[results['length'] > 1][['Terms','Frequency']]
```

Result Set:

```
+-----+-------------------------------------+-----------+
|     |               Terms                 | Frequency |
+-----+-------------------------------------+-----------+
|  4  | Term 2, Term 1                      |       6.0 |
|  5  | Term 3, Term 1                      |       6.0 |
|  6  | Final Exam, Term 1                  |       6.0 |
|  7  | Term 2, Term 3                      |       7.0 |
|  8  | Term 2, Final Exam                  |       7.0 |
|  9  | Term 3, Final Exam                  |      10.0 |
| 10  | Term 2, Term 3, Term 1              |       6.0 |
| 11  | Term 2, Final Exam, Term 1          |       6.0 |
| 12  | Term 3, Final Exam, Term 1          |       6.0 |
| 13  | Term 2, Term 3, Final Exam          |       7.0 |
| 14  | Term 2, Term 3, Final Exam, Term 1  |       6.0 |
+-----+-------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Is there some parameter in apriori to yield the desired result or some other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dot` and `value_counts`

```
df.dot(df.columns+',').str[:-1].value_counts()
Out[419]: 
Term1,Term2,Term3,FinalExam    6
Term3,FinalExam                3
Term2,Term3,FinalExam          1
dtype: int64
```